# Groovy script for Jenkins: execute HTTP request without 3rd party libraries

Tags: rest, http, jenkins, groovy

I need to create a Groovy post build script in Jenkins and I need to make a request without using any 3rd party libraries as those can't be referenced from Jenkins.

I tried something like this:

```
def connection = new URL( "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" +
    URLEncoder.encode(
            "select wind from weather.forecast where woeid in " + "(select woeid from geo.places(1) where text='chicago, il')",
            'UTF-8' ) )
    .openConnection() as HttpURLConnection

// set some headers
connection.setRequestProperty( 'User-Agent', 'groovy-2.4.4' )
connection.setRequestProperty( 'Accept', 'application/json' )

// get the response code - automatically sends the request
println connection.responseCode + ": " + connection.inputStream.text
```

but I also need to pass a JSON in the POST request and I'm not sure how I can do that. Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Executing POST request is pretty similar to a GET one, for example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// POST example
try {
    def body = '{"id": 120}'
    def http = new URL("http://localhost:8080/your/target/url").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    http.setRequestMethod('POST')
    http.setDoOutput(true)
    http.setRequestProperty("Accept", 'application/json')
    http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 'application/json')

    http.outputStream.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"))
    http.connect()

    def response = [:]    

    if (http.responseCode == 200) {
        response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(http.inputStream.getText('UTF-8'))
    } else {
        response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(http.errorStream.getText('UTF-8'))
    }

    println "response: ${response}"

} catch (Exception e) {
    // handle exception, e.g. Host unreachable, timeout etc.
}
```

There are two main differences comparing to GET request example:

1. You have to set HTTP method to POST

   ```
   http.setRequestMethod('POST')
   ```
2. You write your POST body to `outputStream`:

   ```
   http.outputStream.write(body.getBytes("UTF-8"))
   ```

   where `body` might be a JSON represented as string:

   ```
   def body = '{"id": 120}'
   ```

Eventually it's good practice to check what HTTP status code returned: in case of e.g. `HTTP 200 OK` you will get your response from `inputStream` while in case of any error like 404, 500 etc. you will get your error response body from `errorStream`.